# Flutter: List view shows blank or white screen?

Tags: list, listview, flutter

Iam trying to build a product simple page sith coursal and many grid views in single page but it always shows white screen with no data at all !!

I've tried to add SafeArea before column and the same blank screen
any help !!

```
return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
          child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
        CarouselSlider(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
            items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((i) {
              return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/ad.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover));
              });
            }).toList()),
        Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: marginFixed * 2, right: marginFixed),
            alignment: Alignment(1, 0),
            child: Text("الأقسام :")),
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Card(
                          color: StyleCustom().red,
                          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.5,
                                child: Image.asset('assets/ad1.png',
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                            Text("عروض حصرية",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                          ])));
                }))
      ]))
    ]);
```

The Result :
[image]

Comment: Did you check the log to see if there were any errors? Sometimes it doesn't show on screen, but only on the IDE

Comment: here is the log: btw when shrinking the grid view the page become no more scrollable !!
I/flutter ( 2111): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
I/flutter ( 2111): the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
I/flutter ( 2111):
I/flutter ( 2111): User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 2111):   GridView 
lib\screens\home.dart:30
I/flutter ( 2111):
I/flutter ( 2111): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved By Adding :

```
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: ScrollPhysics(),
```

inside the GridView